# tcplistener does not start

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener

I am using a `TcpListener` in a Windows Forms application; which has a 'Start' button that starts the `TcpListener`. However, when I click the start button the following exception is thrown:

> The requested address is not valid in its context

This is the code I am using to start the listener:

```
IPAddress FriendIp = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
server = new TcpListener(FriendIp, PortNum);
server.Start();
```

This is the call stack for the exception:

```
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(System.Net.EndPoint endPointSnapshot, System.Net.SocketAddress socketAddress) + 0x9f bytes  
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint localEP) + 0xd2 bytes 
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(int backlog) + 0x91 bytes   
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start() + 0xa bytes
```

> BlueBall.exe!BlueBall.Chat_Window.Chat_Window(string ipadd, int port, bool serverclientjob) Line 46 + 0x10 bytes    C#
>       BlueBall.exe!BlueBall.BlueBall.Main_ListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 221 + 0x29 bytes    C#
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x7f bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x2c9 bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x13 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x64 bytes 
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x287 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x16c bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes
>       BlueBall.exe!BlueBall.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x1d bytes   C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6d bytes
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x2a bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: The address passed to TcpListener isn't the remote address, it's the local address.

Comment: no, It is remote address, I double checked it.

Comment: Or, I may say.. Its the address of virtual machine on my PC.

Comment: No, you must pass a local address for the listener to bind to. Think about it this way: I can't write a listener to bind to an endpoint on your machine, only mine.

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi no I don't mean the address you passed is the local address, the problem is that it *expects* the local address but you're giving it a remote address.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for help... I will find another PC for experiment now...

Comment: Guys guys, I am getting confused. localaddress = MyIpaddress? Remoteaddress = otherPcIpaddress? right?

Comment: Yes something like that, the local address is the IP address associated with the NIC you want to use to receive. If you set it to IPAddress.Any a sensible default is used.

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi I can see quite a bit of effort went into this question; but if you want to avoid future downvotes avoid "Phone Speak" - it really isn't welcome in this community. Not knowing English is fine, but "Plz" is not a word.

Comment: @downvoters could you explain the downvote please? If you are unhappy with the English the StackOverflow team was kind enough to provide us with the edit capability.

Answer (score 0):

Harold and Spender are correct, the TcpListener can only bind to a local IP Address on the machine where it is instantiated.